# e.g is there is another way to write my echo command for having expected result?

Tags: echo

i want to add this line at the end of [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzc1M.png)my configuration file with echo but i didn't have what i expected to be.
i need help is there something can i change in my echo command ?

```
commande
```

echo -e "\nlint:\e | \n  set -e\n  yamllint .\n  ansible-lint\n  flake8\n" >> initialize_role/molecule/default/molecule.yml

expected result
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQxKg.png)

result
[what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inHk0.png)

echo -e "\nlint:\e | \n  set -e\n  yamllint .\n  ansible-lint\n  flake8\n" >> initialize_role/molecule/default/molecule.yml

expected result
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQxKg.png)

result
[what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inHk0.png)

Comment: i currently want to use this command line in gitlab ci / cd for integration test with molecule but lint is disabled by defaut i need to add this lines for making enabled any help will be great

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I JUST want to add few lines in my existing congi=guration file but it seems not working